# Test case for validating xlsx sheet in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an xlsx sheet which contains person details. While loading the sheet in webApp i am also loading the DB values of that person in the next column. And finally i compare the results.

I need to write automated test case for comparing the sheet with DB .

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can access XLS files with Apache POI or Jxl (https://seleniumeasy.com/jxl-tutorials/how-to-read-excel-file-using-java)
You can then retrieve file info and store them in variables.

Jdbc is commonly used for accessing databases in Java. Here is an example:

```
public ResultSet selectSqlValues(String url, String login, String password, String request) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            Statement statement = connexion.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(request);
            connexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
```

You can then retrieve the database data (for example, like this: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/database/jdbc_result_set.shtml#.WBl1-C2LSUk), then compare it with the values you retrieved from the XLS file.